# How to translate elements within a ngFor-loop in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular6, ngfor, xliff

I have an array of values, that are fixed and not loaded from an external source:

```
fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears'];
```

Now I want to list these values:

```
<li *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" i18n="fruits">
  {{ fruit }}
</li>
```

Now the values should be translated using XLIF:

```
<li>pommes</li>
<li>oranges</li>
<li>poires</li>
```

---

Unfortunately, the extractor creates only a single entry in the XLIFF file, that looks like this:

```
<trans-unit id="some-id" datatype="html">
  <source>
    <x id="INTERPOLATION" equiv-text="{{ fruit }}"/>
  </source>
  <context-group purpose="location">
    <context context-type="sourcefile">test.component.html</context>
    <context context-type="linenumber">1</context>
  </context-group>
  <note priority="1" from="description">fruits</note>
</trans-unit>
```

This is what I was expecting:

```
<trans-unit id="some-id-1" datatype="html">
  <source>apples</source>
</trans-unit>
<trans-unit id="some-id-2" datatype="html">
  <source>oranges</source>
</trans-unit>
<trans-unit id="some-id-3" datatype="html">
  <source>pears</source>
</trans-unit>
```

The translations are extracted using this command:

```
ng xi18n --output-path src/locale
```

---

I also tried to create dynamic translation ids:

```
i18n="@@fruits.{{ fruit }}">
```

… but it's displayed in the XLIF literally as `fruits.{{ fruit }}`.

---

How can I get this to work? Is it even possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48327401/angular-i18n-work-around-for-translations-in-code/50191658#50191658