# How to translate string from server in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

I'm able to translate most of my labels using Angular i18n and AOT compilation. However, I get some strings/keys like 'category.abc' as a result of server calls and would like to translate them as well - in templates as well as in code. How would I go about doing that? I know which keys exists, but of course they will only be inserted at runtime. I don't want to use ngx-translate, as this library will soon be deprecated.

Comment: You need to reuse an existing solution (like ngx-translate), or create your own, or wait until Angular finally improves its i18n support.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48327401/angular-i18n-work-around-for-translations-in-code/50191658#50191658

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for your quick reply. Suppose I could do without the in code translations and only needed dynamic translations in the template, would that change your answer? Would I need to somehow mix AOT and JIT i18n?